# Problem with deleting an entity from other ViewController in CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

people. Im learning how to work with CoreData and i have a question.
I have a "WordArrayEntity" which have oneToMany relationship with "WordEntity" and Nulify deletion rule.
So at first when my app start im fetching info from my CoreData to special array

```
    var wordEntities:[[WordEntity]] = []
```

After it my tableView recieves an attribute that it needs.
As i understand i can delete entities by this method

```
    context.delete(wordEntity)
```

everything works fine when i do this on my tableView.
But, when i move to editor ViewController and try to add new Entity or delete previous nothing happens.
This is my code to move to next view controller

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowWordVC") as? ShowWordVC {
        controller.word = SingleTonForEntities.shared.wordEntities[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        controller.wordIndex = indexPath.row
        self.present(controller, animated: true)
    }
}
```

This is my method to delet word, which perfectly works at tableView

```
    func deleteWordFromVocabulary(word: WordEntity,indexPath: Int) {
    var wordStartsFromLetter = false
    if let firstCharacter:Character = word.englishWord?.first {
        var index = 0
        for array in wordEntities {
            if SingleTon.shared.sectionName[index].lowercased() == firstCharacter.lowercased() {
                var newArray = array
                context.delete(word)
                newArray.remove(at: indexPath)
                wordEntities[index] = newArray
                wordStartsFromLetter = true
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }

    if wordStartsFromLetter == false {
        var newArray = wordEntities[26]
        context.delete(word)
        newArray.remove(at: indexPath)
        wordEntities[26] = newArray
    }

    saveContext()
}
```

When i try to save word after editing or a new one i have the following code

```
@IBAction func saveButtonIsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    keyboardDissapears()
    guard let englishWord = self.englishWordTextField.text,
        !englishWord.isEmpty,
        let wordImage = addedImageView.image,
        let belarusianWord = self.belarusianWordTextField.text,
        !belarusianWord.isEmpty,
        let englishDefinition = self.englishDefinitionTextView.text,
        !englishDefinition.isEmpty,
        let belarusianDefinition = self.belarusianDefinitionTextView.text,
        !belarusianDefinition.isEmpty else {
            createAndShowAlert()
            return
        }
    if editModeIsActivated == true {
        if let wordToDelete = word, let wordIndex = wordIndex {
            SingleTonForEntities.shared.deleteWordFromVocabulary(word: wordToDelete, indexPath: wordIndex)
        }
    }


    word!.englishDefinition = englishDefinition
    word!.belarusianDefinition = belarusianDefinition
    word!.englishWord = englishWord
    word!.belarusianWord = belarusianWord
    let data = wordImage.pngData()
    word!.wordImage = data

    SingleTonForEntities.shared.addNewWordToVocabulary(word: self.word)
    self.createAndShowDoneProgressAlert()

}
```

at first im checking if my fields are empty. If they aren't empty and we are in edit mode i delete the "WordEntity" from our context and then from our array.
And then i try to save a new word and add it to context with this method

```
    func addNewWordToVocabulary(word: WordEntity!) {
    var wordStartsFromLetter = false
    word.englishWord = word.englishWord!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    if let firstCharacter:Character = word.englishWord?.first {
        var index = 0
        for array in wordEntities {
            if SingleTon.shared.sectionName[index].lowercased() == firstCharacter.lowercased() {
                var newArray = array
                newArray.append(word)
                for element in wordEntitesArray {
                    if element.arrayName == SingleTon.shared.sectionName[index].lowercased() {
                        element.addToWordEntities(word)
                    }
                }
                wordEntities[index] = newArray
                wordStartsFromLetter = true
            }
            index += 1
        }
    }
    if wordStartsFromLetter == false {
        var newArray = wordEntities[26]
        newArray.append(word)
        wordEntities[26] = newArray
    }
    saveContext()
}
```

And there is a question. What am i doing wrong?
When i try to add new word to vocabulary - my app crashes.
But when im in edit mode and after it adding a new word to vocabulary - it just returns an empty tableViewCell.
I am new to CoreData and working with for about a week, but i would be glad to here what am i doing wrong and what i should do in such situations.

P.S. Everything worked well with UserDefaults

Comment: When you add or delete a word (assume this is done in the `ShowWordVC`), how do you update the data set and how do you refresh the view in the list (parent) view controller?

Comment: I’be already solved the problem. It was my bad that I didn’t create a new managed object properly.